# A Python Word Processing Function with Word Wrapping

Tags: python, string, list, function, word-wrap

I am building a word processor and am trying to implement word wrapping functionality.

Given a maximum number of characters in a line followed by a list of words, I want to return a collection of strings where each line contains as many words as possible concatenated by a space. The length of each string should not exceed the maximum length.

- There must be exactly one space between each word within each string of the output.
- Each word will be composed of lowercase letters from the English alphabet.
- There will be no punctuation.
- The maximum length of each word can be assumed to be constant.
- No single word will be longer than the given maximum length of characters in a line.

```
import sys

# Prints to standard output.
def wrapLines(line_length, words):
  curr_line = ""
  for word in words:
    if len(curr_line) + len(word) >= line_length:
      curr_line = ""
    else:
      curr_line += word
      print curr_line


def main():
  first_line = None
  words = []

  first_arg = True
  for line in sys.stdin:
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
      continue

    line = line.rstrip()

    if first_arg:
      lineLength = line
      first_arg = False
    else:
      words.append(line)

  wrapLines(lineLength, words)

main()
```

The input:

```
13
abc
xyz
foobar
cuckoo
seven
hello
```

My output keeps printing all the words attached to each other instead of wrapping the line.

```
abc
abcxyz
abcxyzfoobar
abcxyzfoobarcuckoo
abcxyzfoobarcuckooseven
abcxyzfoobarcuckoosevenhello
```

The expected output:

```
abc xyz
foobar cuckoo
seven hello
```

Comment: First thing before I even finish reading your question: **do not use Python 2.x** . It servers you nothing at this time - it will be discontinued in 9 months for good - any project should be using a recent Python. It is easy to install the latest stable Python, even with no administrator access in any OS: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems there - 
the most important one is that you are reading the first line in stdin, and using it as `lineLength`, but you **don't convert it to a number**. Thus, your value in the  `lineLength` (and `line_length` inside the wrapper function) variable is a string - and the comparison

```
 if len(curr_line) + len(word) >= line_length:
```

Always compares the lenght of your proposed output line on the left hand side with a string - if your using a recent version of Python, this line would error, as comaring numbers and strings is now (rightly) forbidden. In Python 3, however, this expression is always True - numberers are always considered as  `<` than strings - so the code for the line exceeding the limit is never run.

The second error is simply that you do not concatenate spaces to your line string  yu simply concatenate the words with `+=` but add no spaces.

The third error is that you always print the line being computed inside the loop - regardless of line lenght being exceeded or not.

And last,but not least - as I stated in the comments above: do not use Python 2 anymore - there is a reason why they made Python 3, and it is because the language evolved.

And, less wrong, but recommended: your function should just process the text, and return data - if you want to print the results, you can print it from the caller function. In that way the function remains generic enough it can be used in other contexts.

Also, the recommended indentation size for Python applications is 4. Although using 2 spaces is valid code, it is virtually not used anywhere (but in private code of some well known companies - but that is their business).

Your fixed code, plus recommendatios - will work both in Python 2 and 3:

```
import sys

def wrapLines(line_length, words):
    curr_line = ""
    result = []
    for word in words:
        if len(curr_line) + len(word) + 1 >= line_length:
            result.append(curr_line)
            curr_line = ""
        else:
            curr_line += " " + word
    if curr_line:
        result.append(currline)
    return result


def main():
    first_line = None
    words = []

    first_arg = True
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if len(line.strip()) == 0:
            continue

        line = line.rstrip()

        if first_arg:
            line_length = int(line)
            first_arg = False
        else:
            words.append(line)

    print("\n".join(wrapLines(line_length, words)))


main()
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation about some finer points of standard coding practices. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as far as I can tell you didn't specify your desired `lineLength` so I'll assume `14` based on your expected output. Personally I think this can all be simplified into a single function that loops through your list of input words and if it can add it without exceeding the line length it will add to a string, otherwise it will add the string to our output list (seeing as it can't handle the next word) and then reset the string. I implemented a `while` loop so on an iteration that it needs to reset it can simply not increment the counter (`i` in my case) and then it will index that same location the next iteration and it will be the first in line to be added to the freshly reset string. I made this in Python 3.X so it may not work in 2.X but if that is the case it would be the `'{}'.format` and you could use the `%` operator instead. At the end of the loop there is another `wrapped_words.append(current_line.strip())` so that we can grab the last line too.

My solution:

```
words_input = ['13', 'abc', 'xyz', 'foobar', 'cuckoo', 'seven', 'hello']

def wrap_words(words_to_wrap, max_line_length):
    wrapped_words = []
    current_line = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(words_to_wrap):
        if len(current_line) + len(words_to_wrap[i]) + 1 > max_line_length:  # +1 for the space
            wrapped_words.append(current_line.strip())
            current_line = ''
        else:
            current_line += '{} '.format(words_to_wrap[i])
            i += 1
    if len(current_line):
        wrapped_words.append(current_line.strip())
    return wrapped_words

print(wrap_words(words_input, 14))
```

Outputs:

> ['13 abc xyz', 'foobar cuckoo', 'seven hello']